# Point markers with icon/picture symbols showing white area around them on ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I'm trying to use some icons (pictures) but i haven't been successful yet.

This is where i got the icons: http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/category/markers/offices/

I want to build a 1 meter by 2 meter tourism map of a specific area of Lisbon using these icons to ilustrate where are the restaurants/bars/banks/supermarkets/etc...

[image: icons]

What happens when i add an icon in the arcmap is this:icones2.jpg

They have this white area around them but i would really like to take it away. I tried to get some help from some photoshop geeks but whatever the solution, when i upload them to arcmap they just don't change and still have the white edge.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS? What format do you have the icons in? jpgs don't support alpha/transparency - you'd need either png (what they save as default from at the link you provide) or bmp format (possibly tif, but we won't go there). Are they being used as point symbology or as labels? Or are you just placing them as graphics?

Comment: As Chris said, convert to PNG and set the transparent colour, you can use IRFanView (http://www.irfanview.com/) to convert and set the transparent colour.

Comment: GNU Image Manipulation Program can be used like photoshop to batch convert jpg to png. http://www.gimp.org/

Comment: Chris: Arcmap 10.2 / PNG / I'm placing them as pictures but maybe as point simbology is the way to go. Do you think so? Because i tried to upload a icon as a point simbology and it kind of worked.

Michael and Mapperz - The icons are in PNG.

Comment: I would create a separate point layer and define that PNG as the symbology as opposed to pasting them as pictures.

Answer (score 3):

Placing images as a picture/graphic (via the Insert menu anyway) doesn't respect transparency of the image by default, and I'm not seeing any way to change that. It also means your images are just graphics, not really tied to a location or any data.

My recommendation would be to create a point layer with at minimum name and type fields. You can then symbolize that layer on Unique Values by type, and edit each type's symbol to be the graphic you want to use. This means your icons will actually be tied to data you can edit and that has a real world location, among other things. The name field can be used for labels. Once symbolized, bring up the Symbol Selector (click symbol in Table of Contents) > Edit Symbol, then change the type to Picture Marker Symbol and browse to where you've saved the icons. You may have to make some sizing adjustments, but by default it should respect the transparency from the PNG.

Note that at the source website you link to, there are different versions of the icons available and some of them have thin white borders (masks) around the icon which are part of it. This is a subtle distinction in some cases from the square extents of the icon image (ie what is supposed to be white vs transparent and if the transparency isn't working at all).